# How to conditionally apply color to list type values in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, html, css, pandas, dataframe

I have the below dataframe:

```
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    d = {'Cell':['A','B','C','D','E'],'D1':[5, 2, 2, 6,6], 'D2':[np.nan, 5, 6, np.nan,3], 'D3':[7,np.nan, 5, 5,np.nan], 'D6':[17, 3, np.nan,np.nan,2],'diff%':[np.nan,[40],[16.67],[16.67,50],[50,33,24]]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(d)

    Cell  D1   D2   D3    D6         diff%
0    A   5  NaN  7.0  17.0           NaN
1    B   2  5.0  NaN   3.0          [40]
2    C   2  6.0  5.0   NaN       [16.67]
3    D   6  NaN  5.0   NaN   [16.67, 50]
4    E   6  3.0  NaN   2.0  [50, 33, 24]
```

1. I want to create a dataframe with the rows where any of the value is greater than 30 in the diff%  column
2. conditionally color code(style) only the values > 30 with bold and red text color styling for creating a html table from the dataframe.

Below is the dataframe that I want:

```
    Cell  D1   D2   D3    D6         diff%
1    B   2  5.0  NaN   3.0            [40]
3    D   6  NaN  5.0   NaN       [16.67, 50]
4    E   6  3.0  NaN   2.0       [50, 33, 24]
```

Please let me know any solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach using lambda, [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) and [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) methods

```py
df1 = df[df['diff%'].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, list) and any(i > 30 for i in x))]
print(df1)
```

---

```
  Cell  D1   D2   D3   D6         diff%
1    B   2  5.0  NaN  3.0          [40]
3    D   6  NaN  5.0  NaN   [16.67, 50]
4    E   6  3.0  NaN  2.0  [50, 33, 24]
```

To apply the color you can use a costume function and [`df.style.applymap()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.applymap.html):

```py
def color_diff(x):
    if isinstance(x, list) and any(i>30 for i in x):
        return 'color: red; font-weight: bold'
    else:
        return ''
df1 = df1.style.applymap(color_diff, subset=['diff%'])
df1
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the solution -->
for color coding , i want to hightlight only the ones that are greater than 30
[40,16,33] -->i want to highlight only 40 and 33 with color, Above code is coloring the entire list if any of the value is greater than 30

Comment: sorry i gave wrong problem statement, i edited the problem statement